# custom iPhone MobileConfig file

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to help my iPhone users to configure my application which is very complex URLs that they need to insert. so I made this available through the settings App.

Can I also give them MobileConfig file to help them just run it on the iPhone from Safari to configure the APP?

If the answer is Yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use config profiles to configure 3rd party apps.

Configuration profiles are for configuration of a device and some system apps only.

Did you considering exposing some simple URL which will contain all complex configurations and your app downloading these complex configurations from this URL?

Comment: I guess that is the best bet but still this means I have to let the user specify the url for the configuration server.

Comment: Do you have multiple different configuration for different users?

Comment: Yes each company would buy the package package and would necessarily have different configurations.

Comment: One more idea for you. Use QR code. You can send an email to customer with QR code which contains a link to configurations (or configurations itself). All they have to do is to point and scan it from desktop/notebook screen.

Comment: That seems to be a great idea. thnx